# Why is my NLog configuration not working on my server machine?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, servicestack, nlog

I am using ServiceStack framework and NLog to do my logging. I can do logging on my local machine just fine. However on the server, it doesn't. I have checked that the `Nlog.config` is in the `bin` directory and the whole directory, including the directory above the `bin` directory has write access.

Below is a snippet of the config file:

```xml
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets async="true">
        <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir}\logs\${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />
        <target xsi:type="Debugger" name="debug"
            header="===== ${date:format=ddd, dd MMM yyyy} ${time} ====="
            layout="${level} | ${logger} | ${message} | ${onexception:${exception:format=tostring} | ${stacktrace}}"
            footer="===== end of session ===== ${newline}"
        />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,debug" />    
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to change the path to something you know?

Instead of `fileName="${basedir}\logs\${shortdate}.log"` to something like `fileName="c:\logs\${shortdate}.log"`?

The `basedir` variable of NLog in web applications don't run inside the bin folder. I think you will find the log files inside

```
%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

If it's a ASP.NET app.

Comment: I am afraid I can't access c: drive as it is an external shared hosting server

Comment: I suggested C:\, but you can use any other folder path that you have access to, and it's not a very good practice for your code to have write permission on your bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

While I do not know specifically what is wrong with your server environment and config I have always found it helpful to check the following:

1. Make sure you know exactly what the directory for the logs is (as suggested by @PauloCorreia).
2. Make sure that directory actually exists.
3. Make sure that the IIS worker process has the correct privileges to be able to write to that directory.

FWIW, it is usually a permissions issue in my experience.